# how to deploy windows phone 10 application to a device?

Tags: c#, powershell, deployment, windows-phone, windows-10

I am using a Nokia lumia630 device, which uses latest windows 10 insider preview build available.

i created a sample windows UWP application and took a build of the same.The output of the build is an Appx.

How can i install this Appx to my device? Anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Deploying apps to Win 10 Mobile is a bit difficult when using the command line tool. A great alternative is the Device Portal that is available under the “For Developer” settings.Its available with the latest build.

[image]

Now You can connect to the device using a web browser and manage apps via the Apps page with no pairing/pin required. This seems to be an easy way of deploying apps than using command line.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft developed a command line tool called WinAppDeployCmd so you can deploy an Universal Windows app from a Windows 10 machine to any Windows 10 Mobile device via USB or WiFi (since they're on the same subnet). That's a perfect solution if you doesn't have Visual Studio, the app source code or you're under a Hyper-V Virtual Machine.

Basically you will need:

1. [Windows 10 SDK](https://dev.windows.com/downloads/windows-10-sdk)
2. Generate the .appx package (PC)
3. Enable the developer mode (Mobile)
4. Turn on the discovery mode (Mobile)
5. Get the code to pair devices (Mobile)
6. Get mobile IP address using WinAppDeployCmd tool (PC)
7. Run command (PC)

The command will look like this

```
WinAppDeployCmd install -file “<path>” -ip <ip> -pin <pin>
```

The tool can be found at C:\Arquivos de Programas (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86\WinAppDeployCmd.exe

You can find a detailed step-by-step tutorial [here](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/06/deploy-remoto-de-universal-windows-apps/)

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio allows you to directly deploy an app to a windows phone. You need to register your windows phone as a development phone with Microsoft. Once this is done, you could use visual studio to do this for you. Not sure if you can deploy windows 10 apps to your phone at the moment. Try this link and see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx Remember to Upvote if this helps.

Comment: @ Jason, you are  right we can deploy the app from VS to device.but my requirement is different.I am having only the Appx file and a device and i need to deploy that to the device.

Comment: Try this maybe: http://windowsphonehub.in/tutorials/tips-wp-8-1-appx-deployment-tool-portable-easy-install-appx-files/

Comment: This tool is not working with windows 10.Its showing some error(Error-there is an error in XML document) when we try to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

You can register your Windows Phone 10 in developer mode. Follow [these steps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn706236.aspx) and you can achieve your goal.

Comment: And then what? Unlocking the device is one thing. Getting the app package recognized is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

When you use device portal like mentioned in the answers above, some might get the following error
"Failed to start deployment. Failure text: Package failed updates, dependency or conflict validation. (0x80073cf3)"

To fix this:
Add the dependencies found under "Dependencies/ARM" folder.Add it here.

[image]

I had to add following dependencies to make it work:
Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0.appx
Microsoft.VCLibs.ARM.Debug.14.00.appx