# copy files from PC to windows phone 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, console-application, windows-10-mobile, opennetcf

I created a console application in c# to copy files from PC to mobile devices and run a setup on the device. I have used OpenNETCF.Desktop.Communication and works fine with most of devices except windows 8.1 and 10 mobile.

Apparently, last versions of windows mobile don't connect to "Sync Server" on windows 10 and that's why OpenNETCF doesn't work.

Somebody knows how to achieve the same thing on this two model of windows mobile?

Comment: Perhaps explore `Windows.Networking.Proximity` namespace in order to share content over NFC and WiFi Direct?  Note I have not done this specific thing myself with the noted versions thus just a comment.  I found an example here:https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-sharing-with-8f629148

Comment: Thanks, I have read the description but I need an USB connection.

Comment: there is no way to "run setup". deploy the appx files to install apps

Comment: If you are trying to deploy/run setup this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636275/how-to-deploy-windows-phone-10-application-to-a-device

Comment: I think I understood what is wrong with my application: I use CF 3.5 and it might not be compatible with Windows 10 mobile. Is it true?

Comment: The compact framework is not compatible with windows mobile 10