# Can't install UWP app from .appx file on Windows 10

Tags: uwp, windows-10, appx

I'm running on Windows 10 and built an .appx file.  My assumption was that I'd be able to double click on the file to install it, but no file association was made.  I updated my settings to allow me to sideload apps, but it didn't change anything.  Am I missing something?  Shouldn't there automatically be a file association?

Comment: you need to allow sideloading of apps in developer settings and you should have an App installer app since Win10 v1607 to install the appx via double click. if you use 1507 or 1511, update to most recent version

Comment: App installer app is not available for Windows Mobile.

Comment: I am also not able to install when the .Net Native toolchain is 1.6 that means UWP platform target in 5.3.2

Comment: @Saurabh he is using Windows 10, not mobile. For mobile, [deploy the appx via device portal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34292601/1466046). if you have a question, ask your own one and not enter other questions

Comment: Want to install app by double click then you can create a bundle file. here is a link for more detail. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps.

Comment: First off, enable side loading.
Next, don't click on the .appx. Instead, you should see a ps1 file in the same folder. Execute that, which will install the certificate.

Comment: @karann-MSFT  i have preapred .appxbudle file from uwp xamarin. now i need to install in windows 10 mobile. so, i have moved bundle file to mobile. i was tried to install but its not installing. after click on install option, no one message shown. it will be closed and not installed.